# How to show Bold and Italic both to My NSString without ThirdParty Libary in Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uifont, nsmutableattributedstring

Here is my code which I attempt :

```
NSString *strFirst = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The App feature is only available to users while at "];
NSString *strAreaName = kAreaName;
NSRange boldedRange = [strAreaName rangeOfString:strAreaName];

NSMutableAttributedString *newAttString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:strFirst];
NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:strAreaName];
UIFont *fontText = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0];

NSDictionary *dictBoldText = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:fontText, NSFontAttributeName, nil];
[attrString setAttributes:dictBoldText range:boldedRange];

[newAttString appendAttributedString:attrString];

[lblFirst setAttributedText:newAttString];
```

**Output :**
The App feature is only available to users while at **America**

But I want **America** in Bold and Italic both.

Please guide me to add in my String.

**Thanks,**
**Mihir**

Comment: Use a font that is bold AND italic.

Comment: You will have combination of Bold and Italic for every type of font.

Comment: `UIFont *boldFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0]; UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits traits = [[boldFont fontDescriptor] symbolicTraits] | UIFontDescriptorTraitItalic; UIFontDescriptor *fontDescriptor = [[boldFont fontDescriptor] fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:traits]; UIFont *boldAndItalicFont = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:fontDescriptor size:17];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you can try below code:

```
//----Creating font dictionary for bold-italic text

UIFontDescriptor *fontDescriptor = [UIFontDescriptor preferredFontDescriptorWithTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];

UIFontDescriptor *fontDescriptorNew;
NSDictionary *dictBoldItalicText;

uint32_t NewStyles = [fontDescriptor symbolicTraits] | UIFontDescriptorTraitBold | UIFontDescriptorTraitItalic;
fontDescriptorNew = [fontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:NewStyles];
UIFont *updatedFont = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:fontDescriptorNew size:17.0];//set your font size
dictBoldItalicText = @{ NSFontAttributeName : updatedFont };

//----------

NSString *strFirst = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The App feature is only available to users while at "];
NSString *strAreaName=@"America";

NSRange boldedRange = [strAreaName rangeOfString:strAreaName];

NSMutableAttributedString *newAttString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:strFirst];
NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:strAreaName];


[attrString setAttributes:dictBoldItalicText range:boldedRange];//Assigning bold-italic attribute dictionary

[newAttString appendAttributedString:attrString];

[lblFirst setAttributedText:newAttString];
```

Tested and working fine.

Comment: Great, happy to help:-)@MihirOza

Answer (score 2):

Its possible with out third party library, you change the label property value at attribute inspector same like below attached image.[image]

Comment: I am using a single label. How it's Possible with attribute inspector ?

Comment: I think it won't work with dynamic. Please see my Question.

Answer (score 2):

This should work :

```
NSString *strAreaName = @"America";
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><font size='7' face='Helvetica'>The App feature is only available to users while at <b><i>%@</i></b></font><html>", strAreaName];
 NSError *err = nil;
    lbl.attributedText =
    [[NSAttributedString alloc]
     initWithData: [html dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
     options: @{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType }
     documentAttributes: nil
     error: &err];
```

Attaching output :

[image]

Comment: but font is different. Any way thanks for your Help. I got my answer.

Comment: You are welcome. You can set any font which you want in the html itself :)

Comment: How can I set default font?

Comment: I have edited the answer. Please check. You can use font tag. Default iOS UILabel font is Helvetica.

Comment: one small request please tell me how to increase size?

Comment: Please check the answer. This should be the html.

Comment: I am sorry  @Nitish actually finally I use UIFontDescriptor. So, I up vote your Answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following code.

```
UIFontDescriptor *fontDescriptor = [UIFontDescriptor preferredFontDescriptorWithTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];

UIFontDescriptor *changedFontDescriptor;
NSDictionary *attributes;

uint32_t existingTraitsWithNewTrait = [fontDescriptor symbolicTraits] | UIFontDescriptorTraitBold | UIFontDescriptorTraitItalic;
changedFontDescriptor = [fontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:existingTraitsWithNewTrait];

UIFont *updatedFont = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:changedFontDescriptor size:0.0];

attributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName : updatedFont };

NSAttributedString *  newAttStringd = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"America" attributes:attributes];
lbl.attributedText  = newAttStringd;
```